# Animation Between Two Images

Tags: android

i have more then one images in arraylist. now i want to show all the images one by one on imageview using Animation (like sliding). for example there is an one image on imageview. i have implement Gesture on imageview. now i stroke from right to left on imageview then old image is gone slowly in left side and new image comes slowly from rightside. it's like transition animation.

please give the response immediatilly.

Comment: "please give the response immediatilly."
You are right, if you don't ask, we wait generally one or 2 hours before answering.. /Facepalm

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the android [Gallery view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html)

it has the animation built in and you can control the duration as well